# Getting Invalid outside procedure error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I get this error (VBA in Excel): `Invalid outside procedure` in the first `chr(34)`

```
Shell (Chr(34)) & "C:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.exe" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & _
"C:\Users\cwr.Diego.Gomez\Desktop\main_test_suite\myTests\Diego.txt" & Chr(34))
```

Could somebody please try to explain why?

Comment: See [Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx). I don't think you are using this function properly.

Comment: Also, you closed the parenthesis too early `(Chr(34)) & [...]`should be `(Chr(34) & [...]`

Comment: Well the thing is, When I run he command in CMD, i type -- pybot namoffiel.txt in order to execute the robotframework. so im sure i have to declare that file somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You must put your line into a sub and not just place it in the editor alone.

Try something like this:

```
Sub MySub()
  Shell (Chr(34) & "C:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.exe" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & _
    "C:\Users\cwr.Diego.Gomez\Desktop\main_test_suite\myTests\Diego.txt" & Chr(34))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as @Sifu says - you have an extra bracket

But if you put everything in a string to start with it'll make it easier to see your syntax errors

```
dim strCmd  as string

strCmd  = """C:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.exe"" " & _
    """C:\Users\cwr.Diego.Gomez\Desktop\main_test_suite\myTests\Diego.txt"""

Shell (strCmd)
```